# Front end in ruby (with java/php framework)

Tags: java, php, ruby-on-rails

I would like to know whether we can build an application with php/java framework (backend in php/java) and ruby as front end??

Answer (score 0):

Since:

- Ruby has HTTP client libraries
- Ruby has means of providing UIs

Yes.

The same applies to just about every programming language out there.

(Assuming you mean "a backend with an HTTP interface")

Comment: Could you please provide me some examples or tutorials(application with php framework and ruby for front end only) so that I can get a clear idea on how to implement it??

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this with another language, called AutoIT.
Basically, I just send a request to the PHP page with a bunch of parameters which specify what the PHP page should do. Then the text returned is returned to the AutoIT program. I have used this for licensing for example, in some of my more basic projects. This in theory, could be done with Ruby so long as you can recieve the data from the webpage (which would make me cry if you can't).

Comment: Could you please provide me some examples or tutorials(application with php framework and ruby for front end only) so that I can get a clear idea on how to implement it??

Comment: Well since I have never used Ruby, I can't provide anything for that, but for the PHP backend, all I did was sent information to the page in the form of arguments, so say for example I needed to send the PHP page the system ID of the computer currently running the program:
Using ruby, I would perform a webpage read of "domain.dns/page.php?systemid=" << systemid
(From my quick google I believe << is a concatenator? Also, systemid can be a variable or whatever).
Then at the start of the PHP page, I test:
$_GET['systemid']
against the database and return 1 or 0. Ruby can handle the rest.